# In Reincarnated as a Slime, what happened to the future spirit in Chloe?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Major anime, manga (vol?), light novel (vol 11?) spoilers. Anime is no where near this point in the story yet.

Chloe gets the future spirit from the dwelling of spirits which we find out is her future self. When Chloe is "killed" with the light particles by Gran, and she goes back in time, does she leave her future spirit self behind?
After the time travel, Rimuru connects Chloe and Chronoa, but the future spirit Chloe is no longer in the picture, right? Or does Chloe now have her, Chronoa, and future spirit her all in her now?